# Is it worth to make a constant for an empty array in Java?

Tags: java

Sometimes I need to return empty arrays to fulfill some classes contracts.

Instead of always creating an empty array:

```
@Override public String[] getDescriptionTexts() {
    return new String[0]; // no texts
}
```

I think it may be better to re-use an empty array from a constant:

```
public class Strings {
    public static final String[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new String[0];
}

@Override public String[] getDescriptionTexts() {
    return Strings.EMPTY_ARRAY; // no texts
}
```

Is this kind of optimization worth it?

Comment: No difference between two codes in terms of performance. You won't notice any difference at all.

Comment: What about memory allocation?

Comment: Definitely worth it. There's no reason not to use a constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance benefits of a static empty array instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301251/performance-benefits-of-a-static-empty-array-instance) that is yonger but has better answers and benchmarks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are semantically equivalent, they are as readable, but using a constant array will be (very slightly) more efficient performance and memory wise.

So I would just go for the constant.

---

A quick micro benchmark shows that the difference is about 1 cpu cycle in terms of performance (0.3 nanoseconds, i.e. nothing really) and that GC activity is higher with the empty array creation (~10ms per 1000ms test or 1% of time spend in GC).

```
Benchmark                                       Mode  Samples    Score   Error   Units

c.a.p.SO27167199.constant                       avgt       10    3.165 ± 0.026   ns/op
c.a.p.SO27167199.constant:@gc.count.profiled    avgt       10    0.000 ±   NaN  counts
c.a.p.SO27167199.constant:@gc.count.total       avgt       10    0.000 ±   NaN  counts
c.a.p.SO27167199.constant:@gc.time.profiled     avgt       10    0.000 ±   NaN      ms
c.a.p.SO27167199.constant:@gc.time.total        avgt       10    0.000 ±   NaN      ms

c.a.p.SO27167199.newArray                       avgt       10    3.405 ± 0.051   ns/op
c.a.p.SO27167199.newArray:@gc.count.profiled    avgt       10  250.000 ±   NaN  counts
c.a.p.SO27167199.newArray:@gc.count.total       avgt       10  268.000 ±   NaN  counts
c.a.p.SO27167199.newArray:@gc.time.profiled     avgt       10   95.000 ±   NaN      ms
c.a.p.SO27167199.newArray:@gc.time.total        avgt       10  108.000 ±   NaN      ms
```

Comment: Creating array every time you need will cause additional GC activity that can decrease your performance if application is running for aa long time. +1

Comment: @AlexR out of curiosity I've also checked the GC impact - it is not that high (1% of cpu time) but not negligible either.

Comment: The GC impact depends on number of such arrays created. If this code is on performance critical path this effect may be significant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you need to use empty array or empty string many times in Java, using a constant is a better idea. If you use a single static constant it will create only one object in memory instant of creating the same object many times.

Answer (score -1):

They have not included a lot of things that could be useful into JDK. What about `EMPTY_STRING`? Sounds very useful too.

I personally tend to use your second approach, i.e. define `static final String[] EMPTY = new String[0]` and then use it.